# Is it possible to create a custom CodeLens adornment?

Tags: codelens

Is there an ability to create your own adornment that can be displayed via `CodeLens`?

I did  a quick search on the web but found nothing to indicate that creating custom CodeLens items is available. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not supported at this time, you can track this visual studio request https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5743423-provide-an-open-api-to-allow-us-to-extend-code-len